# change margins for landscape table

Tags: tables, longtable, width, landscape, height

I got a large table in landscape format after some text. The text before the table uses the standard margins set by `article`. Now for the table afterwards, I would like to change the margins, that is make the table as large as possible but still fit on one page with the associated caption. In the following please imagine the table in landscape format, so the height refers to the vertical distance and the width to the horizontal distance on the landscape page. I am providing some code below to show my problem.

Particularly on the top of the height of the landscape page, there is way too much space from the upper section to the beginning of the caption. Additionally the width should be as large as possible, so the table still fits the page and there is room for the page numbering on the left. Currently the part on the right of the table is cut off.

From my understanding, the margins of the document should be changed just for the table part, or the table creation ignores the margins somehow, at least with regards to the width on the right. The width does not have to be equidistant to the left and right necessarily from my point of view. It's most important to make the table fit on the page.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{titling}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}



\begin{document}

    \lipsum

    \begin{landscape}
%\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
%\footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{@{}
lrrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}}
\caption{This is an arbitrary caption spanning multiple lines. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only.} \\
Name of unit & \multicolumn{1}{l}{History until 1980} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{History from 1981} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Date first found} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Date second found} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info4} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Incr over time} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Other effects} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Spring} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Winter} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Autumn} \\
\hline
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-03-31 & 1945-04-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-01 & 1945-04-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-02 & 1945-04-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-03 & 1945-04-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-04 & 1945-04-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-05 & 1945-04-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-06 & 1945-04-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-07 & 1945-04-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-08 & 1945-04-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-09 & 1945-04-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-10 & 1945-04-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-11 & 1945-04-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-12 & 1945-04-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-13 & 1945-04-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-14 & 1945-04-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-15 & 1945-04-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-16 & 1945-04-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-17 & 1945-04-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-18 & 1945-04-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-19 & 1945-04-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-20 & 1945-04-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-21 & 1945-04-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-22 & 1945-04-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-23 & 1945-04-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-24 & 1945-04-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-25 & 1945-04-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-26 & 1945-04-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-27 & 1945-04-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-28 & 1945-04-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-29 & 1945-04-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-30 & 1945-05-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-01 & 1945-05-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-02 & 1945-05-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-03 & 1945-05-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-04 & 1945-05-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-05 & 1945-05-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-06 & 1945-05-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-07 & 1945-05-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-08 & 1945-05-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-09 & 1945-05-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-10 & 1945-05-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-11 & 1945-05-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-12 & 1945-05-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-13 & 1945-05-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-14 & 1945-05-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-15 & 1945-05-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-16 & 1945-05-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-17 & 1945-05-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-18 & 1945-05-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-19 & 1945-05-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-20 & 1945-05-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-21 & 1945-05-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-22 & 1945-05-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-23 & 1945-05-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-24 & 1945-05-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-25 & 1945-05-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-26 & 1945-05-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-27 & 1945-05-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-28 & 1945-05-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-29 & 1945-05-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-30 & 1945-05-31 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-31 & 1945-06-01 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-01 & 1945-06-02 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-02 & 1945-06-03 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-03 & 1945-06-04 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-04 & 1945-06-05 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-05 & 1945-06-06 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-06 & 1945-06-07 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-07 & 1945-06-08 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-08 & 1945-06-09 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-09 & 1945-06-10 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-10 & 1945-06-11 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-11 & 1945-06-12 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-12 & 1945-06-13 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-13 & 1945-06-14 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-14 & 1945-06-15 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-15 & 1945-06-16 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-16 & 1945-06-17 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-17 & 1945-06-18 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-18 & 1945-06-19 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-19 & 1945-06-20 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-20 & 1945-06-21 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-21 & 1945-06-22 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-22 & 1945-06-23 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-23 & 1945-06-24 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-24 & 1945-06-25 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-25 & 1945-06-26 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-26 & 1945-06-27 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-27 & 1945-06-28 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
\hline
\label{tab:labelxyz}%
\end{longtable}%
%\end{minipage}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

If you have any questions please ask. Thanks for any advice.

Comment: To me it is still a bit unclear what exactly you would like to achieve. Does ' fit on one page with the associated caption'  mean that you want the whole table to fit onto a single page or do you refer to the table overflowing into the right margin and eventually being cut off? Regarding the table being too wide, you might want to consider introducing linebreaks in some of the longer column headers to save some horizontal space.

Comment: @leandriis thanks for the comment. Yes I meant I need the table plus caption fit onto a single page. Ok, considering linebreaks would probably help. If it's not enough the font size must be reduced I assume?

Comment: To be honest, I highly doubt that this table can fit onto a single page. Even if one uses a tiny font size and line breaks in the column header the table barely fits onto the page (regarding the table width) and still needs almost 2 full pages to fit regarding its height.

Comment: @leandriis Oh hmm then I have to think about dropping some columns I guess. What I meant by fit on a single page is only in terms of width. I am using a longtable, so multiple pages for additional rows is fine. Sorry if I was unclear. I changed the table to remove the desc column, that reduces the width a bit.

Comment: in `landscape` you can have your table on two package (using `longtable` as you show in question). so far your table occupy three page

Comment: @Zarko ah ok, I did not know 2 pages is the maximum. Does that lead to problems? I mean it compiles fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you consider the following changes of your document preamble and table layout specification, your table can be fit on three consecutive pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs, longtable, makecell,
            tabularx, threeparttable}
\usepackage{siunitx}        % new
\usepackage{afterpage}      % new
%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
%\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\afterpage{\clearpage
    \begin{landscape}
%\begin{minipage}[b]{\linewidth}
%\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}                   % <---
\begin{longtable}{@{}
                  l
                  *{2}{S[table-format=1.2]} % <---
                  cc
                  *{6}{S[table-format=1.2]} % <---
                  *{4}{S[table-format=1.3]} % <---
                  @{}}
\caption{This is an arbitrary caption spanning multiple lines. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only.}
\label{tab:labelxyz} \\
    \hline
\makecell[l]{Name of\\ unit}
    & {\makecell[l]{History\\ until\\ 1980}}& {\makecell[l]{History\\ from\\ 1981}}
    & \makecell[l]{Date\\ first\\ found}    & \makecell[l]{Date\\ second\\ found}
    & {\makecell[l]{Info1}}                 & {\makecell[l]{Info2}}
    & {\makecell[l]{Info3}}                 & {\makecell[l]{Info4}}
    & {\makecell[l]{Info5}}                 & {\makecell[l]{Incr\\ over\\ time}}
    & {\makecell[l]{Other\\ effects}}       & {\makecell[l]{Spring}}
    & {\makecell[l]{Winter}}                & {\makecell[l]{Autumn}}   \\
    \hline
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-03-31 & 1945-04-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-01 & 1945-04-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-02 & 1945-04-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-03 & 1945-04-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-04 & 1945-04-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-05 & 1945-04-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-06 & 1945-04-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-07 & 1945-04-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-08 & 1945-04-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-09 & 1945-04-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-10 & 1945-04-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-11 & 1945-04-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-12 & 1945-04-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-13 & 1945-04-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-14 & 1945-04-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-15 & 1945-04-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-16 & 1945-04-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-17 & 1945-04-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-18 & 1945-04-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-19 & 1945-04-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-20 & 1945-04-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-21 & 1945-04-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-22 & 1945-04-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-23 & 1945-04-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-24 & 1945-04-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-25 & 1945-04-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-26 & 1945-04-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-27 & 1945-04-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-28 & 1945-04-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-29 & 1945-04-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-30 & 1945-05-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-01 & 1945-05-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-02 & 1945-05-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-03 & 1945-05-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-04 & 1945-05-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-05 & 1945-05-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-06 & 1945-05-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-07 & 1945-05-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-08 & 1945-05-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-09 & 1945-05-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-10 & 1945-05-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-11 & 1945-05-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-12 & 1945-05-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-13 & 1945-05-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-14 & 1945-05-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-15 & 1945-05-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-16 & 1945-05-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-17 & 1945-05-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-18 & 1945-05-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-19 & 1945-05-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-20 & 1945-05-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-21 & 1945-05-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-22 & 1945-05-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-23 & 1945-05-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-24 & 1945-05-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-25 & 1945-05-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-26 & 1945-05-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-27 & 1945-05-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-28 & 1945-05-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-29 & 1945-05-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-30 & 1945-05-31 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-31 & 1945-06-01 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-01 & 1945-06-02 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-02 & 1945-06-03 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-03 & 1945-06-04 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-04 & 1945-06-05 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-05 & 1945-06-06 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-06 & 1945-06-07 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-07 & 1945-06-08 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-08 & 1945-06-09 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-09 & 1945-06-10 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-10 & 1945-06-11 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-11 & 1945-06-12 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-12 & 1945-06-13 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-13 & 1945-06-14 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-14 & 1945-06-15 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-15 & 1945-06-16 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-16 & 1945-06-17 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-17 & 1945-06-18 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-18 & 1945-06-19 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-19 & 1945-06-20 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-20 & 1945-06-21 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-21 & 1945-06-22 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-22 & 1945-06-23 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-23 & 1945-06-24 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-24 & 1945-06-25 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-25 & 1945-06-26 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-26 & 1945-06-27 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
Testunit & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-27 & 1945-06-28 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

[image]

above solution doesn't repeat column headers on each page with table. however this is simple to add to your table code.

Comment: Thanks works perfectly and I learned some new commands!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}` to increase the width of the caption to be equal to the table width, use `\setlength\LTright{-25pt}` to allow the table to occupy some space in the right margin use `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}` to reduce the horizontal white space between table columns and use \makecell` to add linebreaks in column headers. With this, your table will fit onto a single page widthwise and onto three pages heightwise.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[USenglish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{lipsum}


\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[longtable]{LTcapwidth=table}

\begin{document}

\lipsum


\begin{landscape}
  \footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\setlength\LTright{-25pt}%

\begin{longtable}{@{}
    llrrrrrrrrrrrrrr@{}}
\caption{This is an arbitrary caption spanning multiple lines. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only. The text will be repeated multiple times for illustration only.} \\ & & \multicolumn{2}{c}{History} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Date} \\ \cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(l){5-6}
        Name of unit & Desc of unit & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cl]{ until\\ 1980}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cl]{ from\\ 1981}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cl]{first\\ found}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cl]{second\\ found}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info1} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info2} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info3} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info4} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Info5} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cl]{Incr\\ over time}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\makecell[cc]{Other\\ effects}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Spring} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Winter} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{Autumn} \\
        \midrule
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-03-31 & 1945-04-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-01 & 1945-04-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-02 & 1945-04-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-03 & 1945-04-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-04 & 1945-04-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-05 & 1945-04-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-06 & 1945-04-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-07 & 1945-04-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-08 & 1945-04-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-09 & 1945-04-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-10 & 1945-04-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-11 & 1945-04-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-12 & 1945-04-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-13 & 1945-04-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-14 & 1945-04-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-15 & 1945-04-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-16 & 1945-04-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-17 & 1945-04-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-18 & 1945-04-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-19 & 1945-04-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-20 & 1945-04-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-21 & 1945-04-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-22 & 1945-04-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-23 & 1945-04-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-24 & 1945-04-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-25 & 1945-04-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-26 & 1945-04-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-27 & 1945-04-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-04-28 & 1945-04-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-04-29 & 1945-04-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-04-30 & 1945-05-01 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-01 & 1945-05-02 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-02 & 1945-05-03 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-03 & 1945-05-04 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-04 & 1945-05-05 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-05 & 1945-05-06 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-06 & 1945-05-07 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-07 & 1945-05-08 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-08 & 1945-05-09 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-09 & 1945-05-10 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-10 & 1945-05-11 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-11 & 1945-05-12 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-12 & 1945-05-13 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-13 & 1945-05-14 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-14 & 1945-05-15 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-15 & 1945-05-16 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-16 & 1945-05-17 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-17 & 1945-05-18 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-18 & 1945-05-19 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-19 & 1945-05-20 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-20 & 1945-05-21 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-21 & 1945-05-22 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-22 & 1945-05-23 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-23 & 1945-05-24 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-24 & 1945-05-25 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-25 & 1945-05-26 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-26 & 1945-05-27 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-27 & 1945-05-28 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-28 & 1945-05-29 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-05-29 & 1945-05-30 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-05-30 & 1945-05-31 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-05-31 & 1945-06-01 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-01 & 1945-06-02 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-02 & 1945-06-03 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-03 & 1945-06-04 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-04 & 1945-06-05 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-05 & 1945-06-06 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-06 & 1945-06-07 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-07 & 1945-06-08 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-08 & 1945-06-09 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-09 & 1945-06-10 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-10 & 1945-06-11 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-11 & 1945-06-12 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-12 & 1945-06-13 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-13 & 1945-06-14 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-14 & 1945-06-15 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-15 & 1945-06-16 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-16 & 1945-06-17 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-17 & 1945-06-18 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-18 & 1945-06-19 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-19 & 1945-06-20 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-20 & 1945-06-21 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-21 & 1945-06-22 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-22 & 1945-06-23 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-23 & 1945-06-24 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-24 & 1945-06-25 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.59  & 0.59  & 1945-06-25 & 1945-06-26 & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.59  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.23  & 0.23  & 1945-06-26 & 1945-06-27 & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.23  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        Testunit & lives close to sea & 0.14  & 0.14  & 1945-06-27 & 1945-06-28 & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.14  & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 & 0.909 \\
        \hline
    \label{tab:labelxyz}%
\end{longtable}%
\end{landscape}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works fine. I accepted the other answer though, as the author Zarko was slightly faster.